# Reputation on the main site and reputation on meta

Tags: support, se2.0

What's the relationship between one's reputation on the main site and one's reputation on meta? I can't figure it out.

I would like to know only because I want to have 100 reputation on meta so I can downvote the terrible proposed name [DivideByZero](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/31/what-domain-name-to-use/83#83) ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [the FAQ](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/faq):

> Reputation here is entirely derived from the parent website, and synchronized hourly. Your reputation here is the same as your reputation on the parent website. Votes here do not affect your reputation on the parent site. However, you can earn badges here on the meta site.