# Reputation difference between regular site and meta site

Tags: bug, reputation, meta-reputation

[image]

I've noticed a discrepancy between my reputation on the Math.SE website and that on the Meta.Math.SE websites. [This question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316/reputation-on-the-main-site-and-reputation-on-meta) seems to suggest that the two should be the same and that they're updated hourly, but difference persists and I'm fairly sure it's been over an hour. Would anyone be kind enough to explain what might be happening?

Comment: It takes a while for the sites to synch up. Give it a few minutes.

Comment: Your recent reputation changes come from a question you answered $49$ minutes ago, at this time. So less than an hour.