# Is there a way to get some priviliges concerning limited questions per certain amount of time?

Tags: support, feature-request, asking-questions, privileges, rate-limiting

I know I've a lot to do this year (i.e. making a lot of past papers and past editions of maths olympiads both of secondary school and university level) and I want to get the most out of it.

So this leads me to the question above: *"Is there a way to ask more than 6 questions a day and (sometimes I also want to ask questions right after eachother) so can one get a pass for every 20 minutes-one question rule?*

As I've shown for almost a week now I behave and I'm following only the rules.

Comment: It sounds a bit like you plan to be posting at a high rate. That suggests you might not be spending a lot of time thinking about each one before posting. If you want to *get the most* from the problems (as opposed to getting the most out of the site) you should probably think harder in the problems and then bring the questions that block you the most.

Comment: I'm not sure on how I'll tackle this issue. Maybe I will ask some questions to professors or others instead of posting it here. That will reduce the amount of questions. And you're right maybe I should read other perspectives on this matter instead of reading only one book.

Comment: There are many of these limits that do not apply to mods, but in fact I think that mods are also limited and cannot ask more than 6 questions per day. I must admit that I've never really thought about this, as I've never seen a mod come close to asking 6 questions per day. [some other tidbits on mod limits: Voting limits also apply. Editing limits don't. Review limits don't, though mods don't usually do reviews since their votes are binding. Rapid answers still lead to Captcha checks. We can change our usernames without limit, though I don't know why we would.]

Comment: Thanks for the information.

Comment: Warning. Don't even think about creating a second account to get to ask more questions. You will get caught, suspended, and then you won't get to ask any questions at all. I'm not suggesting that you would try such things, but some youngsters have tried that in the past, so I wanted to strike pre-emptively.

Comment: I didn't even think about it. I'll put more time into problem-solving on my own and otherwise I should first look for more theory and then ask if it doesn't work.

Comment: As mentioned in [comments to your yesterday's question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26995/can-i-ask-a-question-two-times-to-get-an-answer-about-the-continuation-of-my-pro), chat is also a place where you can ask question. (Perhaps the question gets less visibility in chat than on the main site - but there is no guarantee that you get answer on the main site, either.)

Comment: But why for god sake the downvote?

Comment: As often mentioned, on Meta down votes have no effect on reputation.  It's possible the downvoter felt you were making a suggestion with which they disagreed, and this is the canonical way that consensus about suggestions is indicated on Meta.

Comment: That's not an appropriate action at all. Just say what is wrong with my post and I'll edit it for the person who downvoted. It's not that hard.

Comment: @hardmath Do you know why I have got 8 points fewer in maths meta than on the math site. It seems I shouldn't have a lot of points in maths meta since I asked a question or three.

Comment: You don't have a reputation in "maths meta" distinct from your reputation on the main Math.SE site.  It's simply a lag in updating the display in Meta from the current status on the main site that accounts for the perceived difference.   Things should equilibrate on Meta within half an hour or so.

Comment: Ok I see.  Thank you for the clarification

Comment: If your question is rather short, I'd also recommend chat. See [List of chatrooms](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26814/list-of-chatrooms)

Comment: Oké, I'll do that.

Comment: @AnonymousI As hardmath said, there really isn't a "reputation on meta" - you can find more info [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/meta-reputation/info). Still, there might be small delay before the *number* displayed here on meta is the same as on the main: [Reputation difference between regular site and meta site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13559).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The enforced delay between questions is lifted at 125 points, so this will soon not be an issue anymore.

However, the restriction of six questions per day will not go away. Moreover, there is a restriction of 50 questions per 30 days.

Comment: Wow, was never even aware of the 50 question limit. But come to think of it, that's less than 2 questions a day, which seems reasonably hittable.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt The limit was introduced on this site [in 2012](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4742/should-we-ask-for-question-quotas-like-those-that-have-been-available-for-the-bi/4770#4770). Actually, there is also [a comment template](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates/4926#4926) with a "warning" about quotas.