# Should there be a notification when a user asks multiple questions in succession?

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

Many of us have seen instances of a user asking multiple questions, often a few minutes apart. When this happens, the user usually puts little to no effort on answering the questions themselves and expect the answer to be handed to them. We definitely want users to actually think about questions before asking them, and I think it's fair to assume that if you're submitting questions one after another, you can't be thinking too hard about any single one.

I'm suggesting the implementation of some upper bound on questions asked by a user in a time frame of something like an hour. This way we could eliminate question spam from users who just want quick answers while encouraging users to think about a question before asking. This may be inconvenient to users who have many thoughtful questions, but I think that if they have a thoughtful question, they can look at that one first before asking a new one.

At worst, if this is too restrictive, I'd at least suggest a notification when a user asks a question when they've already asked a question recently, reminding the user to ask thoughtful questions, and to think about a question themselves before asking it. This wouldn't prevent a user from mass question asking, but at least it would make clear the site's expectations on asking questions.

Comment: I believe there are limits on the number of Questions (new) users can ask, $6$ questions per $24$ hour period and $50$ per $30$ day period.  See thiis [early "status-completed" request](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4742/should-we-ask-for-question-quotas-like-those-that-have-been-available-for-the-bi).  So there is a per hour "throttle" that coincides with the per "day" limit.

Comment: According to this [recent Answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/26999/3111) a twenty-minute gap between Questions is lifted at $125$ reputation.

Comment: Note the Help Center -> Asking topic, [Why is the system asking me to wait a day or more before asking another question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/asking-rate-limited)  It's pretty short on the exact rate limits, but this I would guess is in keeping with not wanting to enable gaming of the system.

Comment: @hardmath Thanks for that information, I should have looked for myself if these limits existed. $6$ over $24$ hours seems a little generous, but if there are limits and an explanation for new users on why they exist, I'm satisfied.

Comment: I'm in favor of making things clearer, but at any rate the Help Center page can serve as link to give new users who seem to be clogging up a Review Queue.

Comment: I really understand the frustration; in particular, when an asker asks, e.g. to evaluate $$\int \frac{1}{4+x^2}$$ Often it is completely answered from start to finish.  15 minutes later the asker asks another question, say, $$\int \frac{1}{9 + x^2}$$...

Comment: The point I'm trying to make very explicit, is that if an asker receives an answer to the first which uses, thinks about the answer, clicks on a provided weblink that takes him/her to "trigonometric substitution" (say [Wikipedia](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiL_NKIwMPWAhVnllQKHVHdDQ8QFgg3MAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FTrigonometric_substitution&usg=AFQjCNEzU7KKfgiY9vNDxt5J62DTOgQx8A) until fully understanding the process, the second question is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @amWhy some users are just lazy :(

Comment: First I am not agree with the words that you've chosen to express your first phrase (notice that my native tongue isn't english), I prefer (if my english is good) start as  *There are some users asking multiple questions...and it seem to me a problem for this site*. If you refer some specific user ask him/her in the Chat room  *Constructive Feedback*, commenting such disruptive behaviour, or with some moderator or contact with the site. Also there are seasons of an academic year when students ask more questions, and that there are strong restrictions on the number of questions asked by users.

Comment: (1/2) @amWhy For $k\geq 1$, write $\int\frac{dx}{k+x^2}=\int\frac{dx}{k\left(1+\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{k}}\right)^2\right)}$, that can be written as $$\frac{1}{k}\left(\frac{1}{1/\sqrt{k}}\int\frac{(1/\sqrt{k})dx}{1+\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{k}}\right)^2}\right),$$ with the purpose to use the integral $\int \frac{f'(y)}{1+(f(y))^2}dy$ (or work with the change of variable). Thus $\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\arctan\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{k}}\right)+\text{constant}$. If an user asking these kind of questions that you evoke don't understand an example (and he/she try do comparisons) tell this proof.

Comment: (2/2) If he/she doesn't understand it today, maybe these users need to overcome a wall in them learning. They have intention to learn mathematics, but not all people can overcome the wall: the vertigo of not learning this easy substitution, or other proof in mathematics being step by step totally logical. On the other hand you need to know that you've answered more than 4500 questions and did 50000 actions. Well, if you had patience in the past, you can have patience in the future (notice that this and your reputation seems stratospheric for me, but the frustation of such users also is high).