# Posting multiple times within a short span

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I was just wondering if I have say, 3 questions posted at the same time within a short period (less than 1 hour). Is this frowned upon by the community, and as it breaking any rules?

Comment: The system does limit how many Questions you can post in a 24-hour period, as well as within a 30-day period.  The details are discussed [in this previous Answer by @quid](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/26999/3111).  I'd say the primary concern is the quality of Questions being posted, e.g. can one really do a good job of composing well-researched Questions in such rapid succession?

Comment: For the reason's @hardmath provides, yes, many would frown on this, unless you spend an entire day preparing, researching, composing and attempting each question, prior to posting the three questions and your work, one after the other

Comment: If the questions are closely related, it's often better to post one of them and then study the answers to see whether you can make progress on the others using what you've learned.

Comment: While I agree with the consensus that asking questions in rapid succession is a red flag, I think it's worth looking at an exception: Questions on MSE are best received if they are relatively short, admit short answer and are reasonably self-contained. Hence, if your actual question is quite complicated and you are uncertain about several details therein, I think it's best to split up that larger question into it's prime components and ask those questions separately. In fact, I currently have a couple of drafts of such questions that I might ask soon, unless I finally find the answer myself.